# custom shortcuts don't work

Tags: texstudio, keyboard, shortcut

I have defined custom shortcuts to emulate Emacs navigation. The effect is that the default keybindings are disabled now (e.g. arrow up), but the new bindings do not work (e.g. ctrl-p). I can't figure out why that is. I am running TeXstudio on Windows 10. The portion including keybindings (I think) in my settings file is this:

```
[texmaker]
Tools\Commands\latex="latex.exe -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
Tools\Commands\pdflatex="pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
Tools\Commands\xelatex="xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
Tools\Commands\lualatex="lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
Tools\Commands\view-dvi=
Tools\Commands\view-ps=C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\OpenWith.exe \"?am.ps\"
Tools\Commands\view-pdf-external=
Tools\Commands\dvips=dvips.exe -o %.ps %.dvi
Tools\Commands\dvipng=dvipng.exe -T tight -D 120 %.dvi
Tools\Commands\ps2pdf=ps2pdf.exe %.ps
Tools\Commands\dvipdf=dvipdfmx.exe %.dvi
Tools\Commands\bibtex=bibtex.exe %
Tools\Commands\bibtex8=bibtex8.exe %
Tools\Commands\biber=biber.exe %
Tools\Commands\makeindex=makeindex.exe %.idx
Tools\Commands\texindy=texindy.exe %.idx
Tools\Commands\makeglossaries=makeglossaries.exe %
Tools\Commands\metapost="mpost.exe -interaction=nonstopmode ?me)"
Tools\Commands\asy=asy.exe ?m*.asy
Tools\Commands\gs=\"C:\\texlive\\2018\\bin\\win32\\rungs.exe\" \"?am.ps\"
Tools\Commands\latexmk="latexmk.exe -pdf -silent -synctex=1 %"
Tools\Commands\quick=txs:///compile | txs:///view
Tools\Commands\compile=txs:///pdflatex
Tools\Commands\view=txs:///view-pdf
Tools\Commands\view-pdf=txs:///view-pdf-internal --embedded
Tools\Commands\bibliography=txs:///bibtex
Tools\Commands\index=txs:///makeindex
Tools\Commands\glossary=txs:///makeglossaries
Tools\Commands\ps-chain=txs:///latex | txs:///dvips | txs:///view-ps
Tools\Commands\dvi-chain=txs:///latex | txs:///view-dvi
Tools\Commands\pdf-chain=txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf
Tools\Commands\dvi-pdf-chain=txs:///latex | txs:///dvipdf | txs:///view-pdf
Tools\Commands\dvi-ps-pdf-chain=txs:///latex | txs:///dvips | txs:///ps2pdf | txs:///view-pdf
Tools\Commands\asy-dvi-chain=txs:///latex | txs:///asy | txs:///latex | txs:///view-dvi
Tools\Commands\asy-pdf-chain=txs:///pdflatex | txs:///asy | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf
Tools\Commands\pre-compile=
Tools\Commands\internal-pre-compile=txs:///pre-compile | txs:///conditionally-recompile-bibliography
Tools\Commands\recompile-bibliography=txs:///compile | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile
Tools\Commands\svn=
Tools\Commands\svnadmin=
Startup\CheckLatexConfiguration=true
ToolBar\CentralVisible=true
StructureView\ShowLinenumbers=false
StructureView\Indentation=-1
StructureView\IndentIncludes=false
Structure\ShowElementsInComments=false
Structure\MarkStructureElementsBeyondEnd=true
Structure\MarkStructureElementsInAppendix=true
StructureView\ReferenceCommandsInContextMenu=\\ref
Files\New%20File%20Encoding=UTF-8
Files\AutoDetectEncodingFromChars=true
Files\AutoDetectEncodingFromLatex=true
Common%20Encodings=UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, windows-1252, Apple Roman
Files\Max%20Recent%20Files=5
Files\Max%20Recent%20Projects=3
Files\Max%20Recent%20Sessions=5
Files\Recent%20Files=C:/Users/peter/Dropbox/latex/hmm_bew/diagramm.tex
Files\Recent%20Project%20Files=@Invalid()
Files\Recent%20Session%20Files=@Invalid()
Files\Remember%20File%20Filter=true
Files\Use%20Native%20File%20Dialog=true
Files\Recent%20Files%20Highlighting=@Variant(\0\0\0\x7f\0\0\0\x10StringStringMap\0\0\0\0\0)
Files\RestoreSession=true
Files\Last%20Document=C:/Users/peter/Dropbox/latex/hmm_bew/diagramm.tex
Files\Parse%20BibTeX=true
Bibliography\BibFileEncoding=UTF-8
Files\Parse%20Master=true
Files\Autosave=0
Files\Autoload=true
Files\Bib%20Paths=
Files\Image%20Paths=
Session\StoreRelativePaths=true
Editor\GoToErrorWhenDisplayingLog=true
Editor\ShowLogMarkersWhenClickingLogEntry=true
Editor\LogFileEncoding=Document
Editor\ScanInstalledLatexPackages=true
Tools\Insert%20Unicode%20From%20SymbolGrid=false
Spell\DictionaryDir=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\texstudio\\dictionaries
Spell\Language=en_US
Spell\Dic=<dic not found>
Thesaurus\Database=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\texstudio\\dictionaries\\th_en_US_v2.dat
Update\AutoCheck=true
Update\UpdateLevel=0
Update\AutoCheckInvervalDays=7
Update\LastCheck=@DateTime(\0\0\0\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0%\x82\xc3\x4\xda\x15\x61\0)
Editor\WordWrapMode=1
Editor\WrapLineWidth=80
Editor\Parentheses%20Matching=true
Editor\Parentheses%20Completion=true
Editor\Line%20Number%20Multiples=0
Editor\Cursor%20Surrounding%20Lines=5
Editor\BoldCursor=true
Editor\CenterDocumentInEditor=false
Editor\Auto%20Indent=true
Editor\Weak%20Indent=false
Editor\Indent%20with%20Spaces=false
Editor\ReplaceTextTabs=false
Editor\Folding=true
Editor\Show%20Line%20State=true
Editor\Show%20Cursor%20State=true
Editor\Real-Time%20Spellchecking=true
Editor\Check%20Spelling=true
Editor\Check%20Citations=true
Editor\Check%20References=true
Editor\Check%20Syntax=true
Editor\Check%20Grammar=true
Editor\Check%20Package=true
Editor\Check%20In%20Non%20TeX%20Files=true
Editor\Hide%20Spelling%20Errors%20in%20Non%20Text=true
Editor\Hide%20Grammar%20Errors%20in%20Non%20Text=true
Editor\Show%20Whitespace=false
Editor\TabStop=4
Editor\ToolTip%20Help=true
Editor\ToolTip%20Preview=true
Editor\ImageToolTip=true
Editor\MaxImageTooltipWidth=400
Editor\ContextMenuKeyboardModifiers=33554432
Editor\ContextMenuSpellcheckingEntryLocation=0
Editor\TexDoc%20Help%20Internal=true
Editor\MonitorFilesForExternalChanges=true
Editor\SilentReload=false
Editor\Replace%20Quotes=0
Editor\Close%20Search%20Replace%20Together=true
Editor\Use%20Line%20For%20Search=true
Editor\Search%20Only%20In%20Selection=true
Editor\Auto%20Replace%20Commands=true
Editor\Font%20Family=Consolas
Editor\Font%20Size=10
Editor\Line%20Spacing%20Percent=100
Editor\Esc%20for%20closing%20log=false
Editor\UseEscForClosingEmbeddedViewer=true
Editor\UseEscForClosingFullscreen=true
Editor\ShowShortcutsInTooltips=true
Editor\AllowDragAndDrop=true
Editor\Mouse%20Wheel%20Zoom=true
Editor\Smooth%20Scrolling=true
Editor\Hack%20Auto%20Choose=true
Editor\Hack%20Disable%20Fixed%20Pitch=false
Editor\Hack%20Disable%20Width%20Cache=false
Editor\Hack%20Disable%20Line%20Cache=false
Editor\Hack%20Disable%20Accent%20Workaround=false
Editor\Hack%20Render%20Mode=0
Editor\Hack%20QImage%20Cache=false
Editor\Completion=true
Editor\Completion%20Case%20Sensitive=0
Editor\Completion%20Complete%20Common%20Prefix=true
Editor\Completion%20EOW%20Completes=false
Editor\Completion%20Enable%20Tooltip%20Help=true
Editor\Completion%20Enable%20Tooltip%20Preview=true
Editor\Completion%20Use%20Placeholders=true
Editor\Completion%20Show%20Placeholders=true
Editor\Completion%20Prefered%20Tab=0
Editor\Completion%20Tab%20Relative%20Font%20Size%20Percent=100
Editor\Completion%20Auto%20Insert%20Math=true
Editor\Auto%20Insert%20LRM=false
Editor\Visual%20Column%20Mode=true
Editor\Auto%20Switch%20Language%20Direction=true
Editor\Auto%20Switch%20Language%20Math=false
Editor\Overwrite%20Opening%20Bracket%20Followed%20By%20Placeholder=true
Editor\Overwrite%20Closing%20Bracket%20Following%20Placeholder=true
Editor\Double-click%20Selection%20Includes%20Leading%20Backslash=true
Editor\TripleClickSelection=4
Editor\todo%20comment%20regExp=%\\s*(TODO|todo)
Editor\insertCiteCommand=\\cite
TableAutoformat\Special%20Commands="\\hline,\\cline,\\intertext,\\shortintertext,\\toprule,\\midrule,\\bottomrule"
TableAutoformat\Special%20Command%20Position=0
TableAutoformat\One%20Line%20Per%20Cell=false
Grammar\Long%20Repetition%20Check=true
Grammar\Bad%20Word%20Check=true
Grammar\Long%20Repetition%20Check%20Distance=3
Grammar\Very%20Long%20Repetition%20Check%20Distance=10
Grammar\Very%20Long%20Repetition%20Check%20Min%20Length=6
Grammar\Word%20Lists%20Dir=
Grammar\Language%20Tool%20URL=
Grammar\Language%20Tool%20Path=
Grammar\Language%20Tool%20Arguments=org.languagetool.server.HTTPServer -p 8081
Grammar\Language%20Tool%20Java%20Path=java
Grammar\Language%20Tool%20Autorun=true
Grammar\Language%20Tool%20Ignored%20Rules=
Grammar\Special%20Rules1=
Grammar\Special%20Rules2=
Grammar\Special%20Rules3=
Grammar\Special%20Rules4=
Dialogs\Last%20Hard%20Wrap%20Column=80
Dialogs\Last%20Hard%20Wrap%20Smart%20Scope%20Selection=false
Dialogs\Last%20Hard%20Wrap%20Join%20Lines=false
Tools\SingleViewerInstance=false
Tools\Show%20Messages%20When%20Compiling=true
Tools\Show%20Stdout=1
Tools\Automatic%20Rerun%20Times=5
Tools\ShowLogInCaseOfCompileError=true
Tools\ReplaceEnvironmentVariables=true
Tools\InterpetCommandDefinitionInMagicComment=true
Tools\SupportShellStyleLiteralQuotes=true
Tools\Search%20Paths=
Tools\Log%20Paths=
Tools\PDF%20Paths=
Tools\Auto%20Checkin%20after%20Save%20level=0
Tools\SVN%20Undo=false
Tools\SVN%20KeywordSubstitution=false
Tools\SVN%20Search%20Path%20Depth=2
GUI\Style=true
GUI\Texmaker%20Palette=false
GUI\Use%20System%20Theme=true
X11\Font%20Family=MS Shell Dlg 2
X11\Font%20Size=8
X11\Style=
GUI\ToobarIconSize=22
GUI\SymbolSize=32
GUI\SecondaryToobarIconSize=16
View\ShowStatusbar=true
Interface\Config%20Show%20Advanced%20Options=false
Interface\Config%20Riddled=false
Interface\MRU%20Document%20Chooser=false
Interface\Language=
Preview\Mode=4
Preview\Auto%20Preview=1
Preview\Auto%20Preview%20Delay=300
Preview\SegmentPreviewScalePercent=150
Geometries\PdfViewerLeft=1706
Geometries\PdfViewerTop=40
Geometries\PdfViewerWidth=827
Geometries\PdfViewerHeight=1310
Geometries\PdfViewerMaximized=false
Geometries\PdfViewerState=@ByteArray()
Preview\ToolbarVisible=true
Preview\AnnotationPanelVisible=false
Preview\CacheSize=512
Preview\LoadStrategy=2
Preview\RenderBackend=0
Preview\DPI=96
Preview\Scale%20Option=1
Preview\Scale=100
Preview=true
Preview\ZoomStepFactor=1.4142135
Preview\Magnifier%20Size=300
Preview\Magnifier%20Shape=1
Preview\Magnifier%20Border=false
Preview\PaperColor=#FFFFFF
Preview\HighlightColor=#FFFF003F
Preview\HighlightDuration=2000
Preview\Sync%20File%20Mask="*.tex;*.tikz;*.pdf_tex;*.ctx"
Preview\AutoHideToolbars=false
Preview\EnlargedEmbedded=false
LogView\WarnIfFileSizeLargerMB=2
Tools\User%20Class=@Invalid()
Tools\User%20Paper=@Invalid()
Tools\User%20Encoding=@Invalid()
Tools\User%20Options=@Invalid()
Quick\Class=article
Quick\Typeface=10pt
Quick\Papersize=a4paper
Quick\Encoding=latin1
Quick\AMS=true
Quick\MakeIndex=false
Quick\graphicx=true
Quick\Author=
Quick\Geometry%20Page%20Width=0
Quick\Geometry%20Page%20Height=0
Quick\Geometry%20Margin%20Left=0
Quick\Geometry%20Margin%20Right=0
Quick\Geometry%20Margin%20Top=0
Quick\Geometry%20Margin%20Bottom=0
Quick\Geometry%20Page%20Width%20Unit=cm
Quick\Geometry%20Page%20Height%20Unit=cm
Quick\Geometry%20Margin%20Left%20Unit=cm
Quick\Geometry%20Margin%20Right%20Unit=cm
Quick\Geometry%20Margin%20Top%20Unit=cm
Quick\Geometry%20Margin%20Bottom%20Unit=cm
Quick\Geometry%20Page%20Width%20Enabled=false
Quick\Geometry%20Page%20Height%20Enabled=false
Quick\Geometry%20Margin%20Left%20Enabled=false
Quick\Geometry%20Margin%20Right%20Enabled=false
Quick\Geometry%20Margin%20Top%20Enabled=false
Quick\Geometry%20Margin%20Bottom%20Enabled=false
Beamer\Encoding=utf8
Tools\Quick%20Mode=-2
Tools\Max%20Expanding%20Nesting%20Deep=10
Tools\Dvi2Png%20Mode=3
Files\Save%20Files%20Before%20Compiling=2
Preview\Remove%20Beamer%20Class=true
Preview\Precompile%20Preamble=true
Tools\Automatic%20Rerun%20Commands=latex|pdflatex|xelatex|lualatex|compile
User\ToolNames=@Invalid()
User\Tools=@Invalid()
Tools\Display%20Names=@Invalid()
Tools\User%20Order=@Invalid()
Tools\Preview%20Compile%20Time%20Out=15000
Tools\Had%20Successful%20Process%20Start=true
Files\Default%20File%20Filter=
PDFSplitter=0.5001953888237592
Tools\Kind\LaTeX=latex, pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, latexmk, compile
Tools\Kind\Rerunnable=latex, pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex
Tools\Kind\Pdf=pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, latexmk, dvipdf, ps2pdf
Tools\Kind\Stdout=bibtex, biber, bibtex8, bibliography
Tools\Kind\Viewer=view-pdf, view-ps, view-dvi, view-pdf-internal, view-pdf-external, view
Crash%20Handler%20Type=1
Grammar\Display%20Error%200=true
Grammar\Display%20Error%201=true
Grammar\Display%20Error%202=true
Grammar\Display%20Error%203=true
Grammar\Display%20Error%204=true
Grammar\Display%20Error%205=true
Grammar\Display%20Error%206=true
Grammar\Display%20Error%207=true
Search\Find%20History=@Invalid()
Search\Case%20Sensitive=false
Search\Whole%20Words=false
Search\Regular%20Expression=false
Search\Highlight=true
Search\Cursor=true
Search\Selection=false
Search\Replace%20History=@Invalid()
Search\Ask%20before%20Replace=false
Search\Escape%20Sequence=false
Preview\Possible%20Grid%20Sizes=1x1, 2x1, 1x2, 2x2, 3x1, 3x2, 3x3
Preview\EditTool=1
Preview\GridX=1
Preview\GridY=1
Preview\Single%20Page%20Step=true
Preview\Continuous=true
Preview\Scrolling%20Follows%20Cursor=false
Preview\Cursor%20Follows%20Scrolling=false
Preview\Sync%20Multiple%20Views=true
Preview\Invert%20Colors=false
Preview\Grayscale=false
Editor\Completion%20Files=latex-dev.cwl, latex-document.cwl, latex-mathsymbols.cwl, tex.cwl
qttwp\userwidth=700
qttwp\compil=1
qttwp\tocdepth=2
qttwp\startindex=1
qttwp\navigation=1
qttwp\noindex=false
qttwp\title=
qttwp\address=
qttwp\browser=\"C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/IEXPLORE.EXE\"
qttwp\contentname=\\contentsname
qttwp\align=center
qttwp\lastdir=C:/Users/peter
qttwp\dviopt=" -Ppk -V"
InsertGraphics\includeOptions="width=0.7\\linewidth"
InsertGraphics\center=true
InsertGraphics\useFigure=true
InsertGraphics\captionBelow=true
InsertGraphics\placement=
InsertGraphics\spanTwoCols=false
Tools\After%20BibTeX%20Change=tmx://latex && tmx://bibtex && tmx://latex
User\New%20Key%20Replacements%20Created=true
keysetting\size=0
changedLatexMenus=@Variant(\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\0)
CustomToolBar=@Invalid()
FileToolBar=@Invalid()
EditToolBar=@Invalid()
ToolsToolBar=@Invalid()
MathToolBar=@Invalid()
FormatToolBar=@Invalid()
TableToolBar=@Invalid()
DiffToolBar=@Invalid()
CentralToolBar=@Invalid()
customIcons=@Variant(\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\0)
customHighlighting=@Variant(\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\0)
customCommands=@Invalid()
Symbols\UsageCount=@Variant(\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\0)
Symbols\FavoriteIDs=@Invalid()
Symbols\hiddenlists=
StructureView\SingleDocMode=false
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\Ctrl%2BShift%2B%3F=16386
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\%23Ctrl%2BZ=16385
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\Alt%2BY=16388
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\%23Up=4097
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\%23Down=4098
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\Ctrl%2BB=4099
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\Ctrl%2BN=4098
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\Ctrl%2BW=16389
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\Alt%2BB=4101
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\%23Left=4099
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\%23Ctrl%2BC=16387
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\%23End=4104
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\Ctrl%2BF=4100
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\Ctrl%2BE=4104
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\%23Ctrl%2BV=16388
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\%23Ctrl%2BY=16386
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\%23Right=4100
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\%23Ctrl%2BX=16389
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\Alt%2BW=16387
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\Alt%2BF=4102
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\%23Home=4103
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\Ctrl%2BA=4103
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\Ctrl%2BDown=16391
Editor%20Key%20Mapping%20New\%23Ctrl%2BIns=16387
```

Comment: You need to also disable the corresponding shortcuts in the Menus/Menus PDF-viewer sections as well. For example the first one, Ctrl+B is still set to Boldface in `Menus -> LaTeX -> Font styles`. Set that to `<none>` then your 'move cursor left' should work.

Comment: Ok, I tried exactly that for other shortcuts and it did not do anything. For example I have set `Select all` to `<none>` and `Move cursor to line start` to `Ctrl+A`... but `Ctrl+A` still selects the entire document. I case of `Ctrl+B` it worked though. Any idea about `Ctrl+A`?
(TeXstudio needs a reverse shortcut search...)

Comment: Okay, found most of those now. But I still can't figure out how to disable the menu shortcuts like `Alt+E` and `Alt+W`.